# Finding last row in selected numbers of columns, can't use end(xldown)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set of columns ( column : "C:I" on the excel sheet ) which I want to select the last cells of. The issue is that I can't use xldown because there are some blank cells in the beginning of the columns...

How to effectively select the last row anyway? I'¨m trying Range("C1:I1").rows.end(xldown) but it gets stuck right at the beginning at the last non-empty cell after the empty ones.

Comment: use `xlup` that is the usual solution to this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error Finding Last Used cell In VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the columns are filled in an irregular fashion, then:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim N As Long, M As Long, mm As Long
    M = 0
    For N = 3 To 9
        mm = Cells(Rows.Count, N).End(xlUp).Row
        If mm > M Then
            M = mm
        End If
    Next N
    Cells(M, 1).EntireRow.Select
End Sub
```

For example:

[image: see]

Note that the attractive:

```
Sub dural()
    Range("C:I").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Select
End Sub
```

Will select row #18 by mistake!

Comment: +1 bob on. I was about to attempt the required loop but beaten to it!

Answer (score 2):

An example which works on a single column:

```
Sub findLastCellInColumnA()

Dim lstRow As Integer
lstRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(Excel.xlUp).Row
Cells(lstRow, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: The issue is that I don't want to have the entire row but only the values for column C to I, thus not for column A and B